# JUnit reporter generates empty xml file

Tags: webdriver-io

I am using webdriverIO 5 and Cucumber with junit reporter. I have feature file which has only 1 scenario. I marked that scenario with @Ignore annotation in order for it to be skipped at the moment when running tests.
However, Junit report generates an empty/blank xml file for that feature. 
This is causing publishing issues in Azure since it tries to publish contents of the file which is empty.
Do you know how to configure junit reporter in such way that it doesn't generate empty xml file for the feature which hasn't been ran?
Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you can create an MCVE you may want to report to to makers of Cucumber

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje what exactly is necessary to create MCVE? do I need to provide sample project on GitHub? Or is it good enough to provide detailed description?

Comment: A sample project is easier to work with and contains all the details. So definitely prefered.